# Ionic Actionsheet horizontal buttons

Tags: ionic-framework

How can we add horizontal buttons and text field in Ionic Actionsheet.
can we retrive data from textfield. i am able to create buttons vertically, not able to add buttons vertically and get text from textfield.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please attach some code you tried to use to achieve the result.

Comment: You can try tweeks with css class 'action-sheet' in you ionic.css file

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot manipulate actionsheet style as cordova use the native of each platform. If you need custom action sheet you may build actionsheet-like component by yourself or you can use [Angular Material Bottom Sheet](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/bottomSheet)

Answer (score 0):

The Actionsheet is a native plugin. You can edit those in the plugins folder. However, you have to write native code. If you are looking for another (non-native) way, just google angular-modal and roughly a 1000 great options will come up for directives which you should be able to implement easily.